# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' C# datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

tengo esta clase coleccion con un metodo de tipo void que me da el error 
'No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'' 
al momento de querer ponerlo en un datagrid.itemsSource

```
    static Coleccion()
        {
            //
            // Allocate the list.
            //
            _misClientes = new List<object>();
        }
        public static void Record(object value)
        {
            //
            // Record this value in the list.
            //
            _misClientes.Add(value);
        }
    public static void Mostrar()
    {
        //

        // Write out the results.
        //
        foreach (var value in _misClientes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

    }


}
```

}
    }`

este es el metodo en la clase consultar

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            dgClientes.ItemsSource = Coleccion.Mostrar() ; // aquí me da el error.
            dgClientes.Items.Refresh(); 

        }
    }
}
```

lo que quiero lograr es mostrar la coleccion "misClientes" en el datagrid. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que cambiar la firma de tu metodo. Como te dice el error es `void` y este mismo no devuelve nada.
Por otro lado en en el metodo Mostrar estas sacando por pantalla y luego lo quieres asignar a un DataGriedView.

Porque le pasas object en lugar de tu Clase Cliente que seguramente tenes?

```
public static List<object> Mostrar()
{
    //

    // Write out the results.
    //
    foreach (var value in _misClientes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
  return _misClientes;

}
```

Comment: GRACIASSSSS!
no sabia que se podia cambiar la firma por un List<object>.
y respondiendo a tu pregunta si te refieres a esto: `_misClientes = new List<object>();`
es porque los datos de cliente se los paso en otra clase.